# Zero Inflated Negative binomial distribution

Tags: r, distribution, sample

I need help with following task in R:
Generate 10000 sample from a Zero Inflated Negative binomial distribution (each sample has 30 observations).
I found function [`rzinbinom()`](https://rdrr.io/rforge/countreg/man/zinbinom.html) but can't figure out the value of the parameters to input; we are not given them in assignment. Are there default values we can input to make the function work?

Comment: That seems like an unclear assignment - I'd suggest asking your instructor for clarification.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The zero-inflated negative binomial has three parameters: the probability of 0, and then the two "classic" negative binomial parameters. There are about a dozen ways to parameterize the standard negative binomial, which leads to confusion. In R, the two are classically the mean and the `size`, the latter being equivalent to "r" in Klugman-Panger-Willmot or the alpha of the mixing gamma if considering the NB as a Poisson with a gamma prior.

What this means is that even knowing the expected value of each sample, which is what I presume is meant by "each sample has 30 observations", is insufficient to determine precisely **which** ZINBINOM to use. There are literally countably infinite possibilities with varying pi and size which have mean 30. Either your teacher wanted you to pick *any* set of parameters that work or your instructions were insufficient.